# Difference between module <name> = struct .. end and module type <name> = struct.. end?

Tags: module, ocaml

```
module <name> =
   struct 
     .. 
   end;;


module type <name> =
    struct (* should have been sig *)
      .. 
end;;
```

Comment: Did you try compiling your `module type Name  = struct ... end` before asking?

Comment: I just wanted to illustrate an example. I was working on a big module and realized that i didnt want to distract people from the actual question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first declares a module and the second declares a module type (aka a signature). A module type contains `type` and `val` declarations, whereas a module can contain definitions (e.g., `let` bindings). You can use a signature to restrict the type of a module, much as you might for a function. For example,

```
module type T = sig
  val f : int -> int
end

module M : T = struct
  let f x = x + 1
  let g x = 2 * x
end
```

Now, we have

```
# M.f 0 ;;
- : int = 1
# M.g 0 ;;
Error: Unbound value M.g
```

`M.g` is unbound because it's hidden by the signature `T`.

Another common way to use module types is as arguments to and return values of functors. For example, the `Map.Make` functor in [the standard library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html) takes a module with signature `Map.OrderedType` and creates a module with signature `Map.S`

P.S. Note that there's a mistake in the question. A module type is declared using

```
module type <name> = sig
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

A **structure** (written `struct … end`) is a bunch of *definitions*. Any object in the language can be defined in a module: core values (`let x = 2 + 2`), types (`type t = int`), modules (`module Empty = struct end`), signatures (`module type EMPTY = sig end`), etc. **Modules** are a generalization of structures: a structure is a module, and so is a **functor** (think of it as a function that takes a module as argument and returns a new module). Modules are like core values, but live one level above: a module can contain anything, whereas a core value can only contain other core values¹.

A **signature** (written `sig … end`) is a bunch of *specifications* (some languages use the term *declaration*). Any object in the language can be specified in a module: core values (`val x : int`), types (`type t = int`), modules (`module Empty : sig end`), signatures (`module type EMPTY = sig end`), etc. **Module types** generalize signatures: a module type specifies a module, and a module type that happens to specify a structure is called a signature. Module types are to modules what ordinary types are to core values.

Compilation units (`.ml` files) are structures. Interfaces (`.mli` files) are signatures.

So `module Foo = struct … end` defines a module called `Foo`, which happens to be a structure. This is analogous to `let foo = (1, "a")` which defines a value called `foo` which happens to be a pair. And `module type FOO = sig … end` (note: `sig`, not `struct`) defines a module type called `FOO`, which happens to be a signature. This is analogous to `type foo = int * string` which defines a type called `foo` which happens to be a product type.

¹ 
<sub>This is in fact no longer true since OCaml 3.12 introduced first-class modules, but it's close enough for an introductory presentation.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

module type describe a module. It is the same as the difference between .ml and .mli